# How can you get the flutter visible page's state or context?

Tags: flutter

Sometimes an event (eg upload) starts async while the user is on one page.  If they navigate away from that page the task's `.then(...)` will try to display the result on the page which is no longer visible, eg by means of a toast.

How can I get the context of the currently visible page at the time when the Future completes to display a snackbar, toast or dialog?

EDIT:
I see in the description of oktoast (https://pub.dev/packages/oktoast) that version 2 "Does not need the buildContext to be passed", and further

Quote:

> Explain #
>
> There are two reasons why you need to wrap MaterialApp
>
> Because this ensures that toast can be displayed in front of all other
>   controls Context can be cached so that it can be invoked anywhere
>   without passing in context

This implies to me that there is a better way by providing a Material app ancestor somewhere....

Answer (score 0):

For a simple Solution I would use the Provider Package. Keyword here is StateManagement (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

The Model would look sth like this:

```
class UploadModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final bool loading = false;

  void uploadXY() async{
    loading = true;
    // This call tells the widgets that are listening to this model to rebuild.
    notifyListeners();
    await realUploadStuff();
    loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

To start the upload:

```
Provider.of<UploadModel>(this).uploadXY()
```

To react if loading-bool changes:

```
if(Provider.of<UploadModel>(this).loading)...
```

You can find a simple Example here:
https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_counter/lib/main.dart